# Can't refresh page and hold selected value on jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Here is my jsp page code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="test.Obiekt"%>
<%@ page import="test.ListaObiektow"%>
<%@ page import="test.Termin"%>
<%@ page import="test.ListaTerminow"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>menu główne</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


<meta name="android-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="android-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

<link href="css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/ratchet-theme-android.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="js/ratchet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Refresh(idObiekt){
    location.href="pilkaNozna.jsp?idObiekt=" + idObiekt; 
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    <header class="bar bar-nav">
        <a class="icon icon-left-nav pull-left" href="wyszukaj.jsp"></a>
        <h1 class="title">Wybierz obiekt</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="tabelawybor">

            <b>Wybierz obiekt:</b>
            <%
                ArrayList<Obiekt> list = new ListaObiektow().getObiekty();
            %>
            <form name="obiekt">
                <select name="obiekt" onChange="Refresh(this.value)">

                    <%
                    for (Obiekt obiekt : list) {
                        String selectedObiekt = request.getParameter("obiekt");
                %>
                    <option value="<%=obiekt.idObiekt%>"
                        <%= ((Integer.toString(obiekt.idObiekt)).equals(selectedObiekt))?"selected":""%>><%=obiekt.nazwa%>
                        <%=obiekt.adres%></option>
                    <%
                    int idObiekt = obiekt.idObiekt;
                        request.setAttribute("idObiekt", idObiekt);

                %>
                    <%
                    }
                %>

                </select>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="tabelawybor">
            <td><b>Wpisz liczbę uczestników:</b><input type="text"
                name="uczest" /></td>
        </div>

        <div class="tabelawybor">
            <table class="center">

                <tr>
                    <td>Nazwa obiektu:</td>
                    <td>Data:</td>
                    <td>Godzina</br> rozpoczęcia:
                    </td>
                    <td>Godzina</br> zakończenia:
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    ArrayList<Termin> lista = new ListaTerminow().getTerminy();
                    for (Termin termin : lista) {
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=termin.nazwaObiektu%> <%=termin.adresObiektu%></td>
                    <td><%=termin.dzien%></td>
                    <td><%=termin.odKtorej%></td>
                    <td><%=termin.doKtorej%></td>
                    <td><form action="Rezerwuj" method="post">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Zarezerwuj</button>
                        </form></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

ListaTerminow.java

```
package test;

import test.ConnectionClass;
import test.ListaObiektow;
import test.Obiekt;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import test.ListaObiektow;
public class ListaTerminow {
    Connection conn;
    int idObiekt;
    public ListaTerminow() throws SQLException
    {
        conn = ConnectionClass.Polacz();
    }


    public ArrayList<Termin> getTerminy() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ArrayList<Termin> terminy = new ArrayList<Termin>();


        ResultSet rs = null;

        String query = "SELECT obiekty.nazwa,obiekty.adres, termin.dzien, termin.odKtorej, termin.doKtorej FROM termin LEFT JOIN obiekty ON termin.idObiekt = obiekty.idObiekt WHERE termin.czyZajety = false AND obiekty.idObiekt = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        ps.setLong(1, idObiekt);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();



        while(rs.next())
        {
            Termin termin = new Termin();

            termin.setNazwaObiektu(rs.getString(1));
            termin.setAdresObiektu(rs.getString(2));
            termin.setDzien(rs.getDate(3));
            termin.setOdKtorej(rs.getString(4));
            termin.setDoKtorej(rs.getString(5));
            terminy.add(termin);
        }
        return terminy;
    }
}
```

I found solution to refresh and remember value after select option from select form. But now, i want to show all "termins" in  below select form. For example: When i select first option in select form (obiekt.idObiekt = 1) then i want to show all termins for obiekt with id 1 in . Can you help me ?

Comment: Have you considered [cookies](https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/jsp/jsp-cookie.php)?

Comment: No, I have not. I would prefer javascript.

Comment: You need to preserve state client-side. To do that, you need to use a cookie, localStorage or a querystring parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, put your select inside a form. So that when you submit it during refresh you can get the value it was holding with String selectedObiekt=request.getParameter("obiekt"). Then modify your option to read

```
<option value="<%=obiekt.idObiekt%>" <%= ((Integer.toString(obiekt.idObiekt)).equals(selectedObiekt))?"selected":""%>><%=obiekt.nazwa%>
                    <%=obiekt.adres%></option>
```

Comment: Should i use <form> only or should i use <form name="obiekt"> ? Anyway, eclipse calls syntax error ( insert ")" to complete Expression)

Comment: i have edited my post. A closing bracket was missing

Comment: Ok. There is a problem, because idObiekt is of integer type. As far i know, integer is primitive type, so I can't use .equals clause, can i ?

Comment: I have no errors, but i still dont have any rows in my table below this select Form. I think something is wrong with class. Thank you

Comment: ok. Check it out. If you cannot figure it out, you can always return and tell what you have. You will definitely get help.

Comment: You can bring String selectedObiekt = request.getParameter("obiekt"); outside the first for loop. And there is no need to be putting and replacing the id in the session. Do not put anything in session for the moment. Then tell what you have when you run your app

Comment: It still shows nothing. There must be a problem in ListaTerminow.java class, exactly in MySQL query. It must be another way to put idObiekt into query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79996/discussion-between-paul-ngom-and-abecadlo).